# How to create a clickable checkbox in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I want a clickable checkbox there are two checkboxes in a row of my code i want them to be clickable

secondly when either one of them is clicked the second one should be disabled automatically.

Here is my code:

```html
Row(
                             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                             children: [
                               Expanded(child:
                               CheckboxListTile(
                                 title: Text("Yes"),

                                 controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading, value: null, onChanged: (bool value) { },
                               ),
                               ),
                               Expanded(child:
                               CheckboxListTile(
                                 title: Text("No"),value:false,onChanged:(bool value) {},
                                 controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                               ),
                               )

                             ],
                           ),
```

I am trying to acheive this but unable to do so any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
bool firstCheck = false;
bool secondCheck = false;
Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Expanded(child:
                CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text("Yes"),

                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading, value: firstCheck, onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      firstCheck = value;
                      secondCheck = !value;
                    });
                },
                ),
                ),
                Expanded(child:
                CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text("No"),value:secondCheck,onChanged:(bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      firstCheck = !value;
                      secondCheck = value;
                    });
                },
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                ),
                )

              ],
            ),
```

Comment: I have 12 of them in pair do i need a variable for each of them?

Comment: then you used radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

You should use radio buttons:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio-class.html